# LeaderLatch vs LeaderSelector

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

what is the difference between LeaderLatch and LeaderSelector in the apache curator framework?

http://curator.incubator.apache.org/curator-recipes/leader-election.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`LeaderLatch` is simpler to use but `LeaderSelector` gives you more control.  It depends on how much control you need.

Check out [this presentation](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7540961/zk_leader_election.pdf) that I did and the gists that it links to for more details.

Comment: File not found!

Answer (score 34):

They are different abstractions for the same behavior. LeaderSelector was written first (NOTE: I'm the main author of Curator). It uses a callback mechanism. Some Curator users wanted something that looked more like the JDK CountDownLatch, so I wrote LeaderLatch based on those requests. They both accomplish the same thing: leader election. Use whichever suits your needs.

Comment: In the docs, it is mentioned that I should consider using LeaderSelector to run the Reapers as they don't need to run in every client. Why is that?

Comment: Only one server needs to reap. It's overkill to have multiple clients reaping. It could also hurt performance.

Comment: I would like leader election to be done each time isLeader is called to give some randomness to the process that handles a critical path. I don't see an easy way to do this?

Comment: As I understand there will be one leader and multiple followers. But if the use case demands that only one host (leader) executes the code and others just sit idle doing nothing or block, does this framework help ? In other words, if leader is restarted, the others should not get leader privilege. Only the host which is leader initially should retain the authority. is there more detail documentation around the behavior ?